# What is the difference between normalization and re-scaling?

Tags: statistics, normalization, feature-scaling, transformation

This site does not describe the nature of the [normalization](/questions/tagged/normalization) tag. Does it differ from re-scaling? Many authors use the two terms interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

Re-scaling means that you multiply your variable by a factor, i.e. $x \to x/a$. A normalization is a specific kind of re-scaling, where the factor $a$ is such that the values of $x$ become of order one. Its form depends on the context and what you are trying to do. Examples are $a= \langle x \rangle$ or $a= \textrm{max}(x)$. Perhaps the most common one is when you do $x \to (x-\langle x \rangle)/\sigma$, because if $x$ follows a Gaussian distribution, the re-scaled variable follows a normal distribution (average 0 and std 1). Note, this last transformation actually involves a re-scaling, but also a translation.

Comment: what does "your variable" mean ? what's x and a ?

Comment: "Your variable" means a random variable your aim to re-scale. $x$ is the random variable. $a$ is the factor.

Comment: Gaussian distribution is also called normal distribution. It is the standard normal distribution that produces mean of deviations equal to zero and variance equal to 1. Terming it re-scaling or normalization is incorrect.

Comment: In which sense $x \to (x-\langle x \rangle)/\sigma$ is not a re-scaling (after a translation) and, more specifically, a normalization?

Comment: If a=⟨x⟩ = mean, and its division by standard deviation , it generates probability /normal distribution - perhaps also called standard score distribution/standard normal distribution. Re-scaling the data entails observed data minus minimum score and division by maximum Range of data. It is different from mathematical statistics.

Comment: I answered in the most general sense, not only for statistics. If you have $x=1$ in the scale of meters and want it on the scale of km, you need to re-scale it as $x \to x/1000$. That is a re-scaling operation by definition. However, as I said, what factor you use in the re-scale depends on your context (so you might see that sometimes the factor is i.e. a range). On the other hand, normalization denotes a re-scaling to make the numerical value of something become of order unity. Why do you think that when one divides a vector by its norm, you get a so-called unit vector?

Comment: When you say that "Re-scaling the data entails observed data minus minimum score and division by maximum Range of data" that's just an example of a possible re-scaling. There are many ways in which something can be re-scaled. And note that my answer applies only to mathematical statistics after the sentence "if $x$ follows a Gaussian distribution". Before that is general.